# How to add up total score on quiz questions in VB? current not working

Tags: vb.net

This is how I have set a procedure to mark the quiz questions, but I can only ever get a total score of 1 ( if the first answer is correct ) and the other questions are not marked.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
Private Sub GetQuestions()

    questions = {{"General statements of what  a business intends to achieve.  Precise   details of those intentions are set out in objectives", "Corporate strategies", "Corporate objectives", "Aims / goals", "Aims / goals"}, _
            {"A statement of the overall   purpose of the business", "Mission statement", "Social responsibility", "Functional objectives", "Mission statement"},
            {"Objectives that relate to   the business as a whole.Usually set   by top management", "Business unit strategy", "Functional objectives", "Corporate objectives", "Corporate objectives"},
            {"The way in which a business   meets its responsibilities to society as a key external stakeholder", "SWOT analysis", "Social responsibility", "SMART objectives", "Social responsibility"},
            {"How a business attempts to   compete successfully in a particular market", "Business Objectives", "Business unit strategy", "SWOT analysis", "Business unit strategy"}}

End Sub


Private Sub MarkTest()
    FileClose(1)
    FileOpenStatusTS = False

    Dim Topic1Score As Integer = 0


    For i = 0 To 2

        If answers(i) = questions(i, 4) And FileOpenStatusTS = False Then

            Topic1Score += 1
            TotalScore += 1



            FileOpen(1, FilenameTS, OpenMode.Append)
            FileOpenStatusTS = True
            WriteLine(1, Username, Topic1Score)
            FileClose(1)

        End If

    Next

    LblQuestion.Text = "Well done the test has finished!"

    LblDefinition.Text = "You scored " & Topic1Score & " out of " & answers.Length & "!"

    Option1.Enabled = False

    Option2.Enabled = False
    Option3.Enabled = False

    btnPrev.Enabled = False

    btnNext.Enabled = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You set FileOpenStatusTS to true, but then never set it to false again, so the 'if' statement can only evaluates to true once